# Get more information on applet error

Tags: html, applet

I got a Java Applet which gives an error, but when clicking on the error to get more information it open te console. The console, in this case, doesn't give much information. (Output bellow). I have this issue both in Chrome and Firefox.

```
Java Plug-in 10.0.0.147
Using JRE version 1.7.0-b147 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Roel
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
Detected from bootclasspath: C:\\PROGRA~2\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\deploy.jar
```

When opening the applet from a local html page does work but, when opening it from an http page it doesn't. Maybe, that is where the problem arises? However there is not much difference between the code locally and on the web.

Local html

```
<applet code="aphone.AppletA.class" 
        width="100" 
        height="100" 
        codebase="build/classes" 
        archive="APhone.jar?v=9999920,../../asterisk-java-iax-1.0.0-20110228.230315-670.jar, ../../plugin.jar?v=9999998" 
        name="phone"></applet>
```

Http HTML

```
<applet code="AppletA.class" 
        width="100" 
        height="100" 
        codebase="build/classes" 
        archive="APhone.jar?v=9999921,../../asterisk-java-iax-1.0.0-20110228.230315-670.jar, ../../plugin.jar?v=9999998" 
        name="phone"></applet>
```

Comment: Why you remove de package "aphone" from the reference to the class in the second applet? You already tried using the same html that works locally?

Comment: Auch, adding the package back to the reference did the job. Don't no what i did wrong the first time because the code was exactly the same as the local version.

Comment: Then I'll put that solution as the answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the package "aphone" in the reference to the class in the second applet.